# linear recursion $y_n=A \cdot y_{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recursion

Let $a,b, \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_0=a, x_1=b$ and $x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}}{2}$ for $n \geq 2$

(i) Write the recursion in the form $y_n=A \cdot y_{n-1}$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$   matrix and $y_i=\begin {pmatrix} x_i \\ x_{i-1} \end{pmatrix}$

(ii) Find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $S$, so that $A=SDS^{-1}$

(iii) Calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S^{-1}A^nS$

(iv) Deduce from that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^n$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n$

My solution so far:

(i) $\begin {pmatrix} x_i \\ x_{i-1} \end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}  \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin {pmatrix} x_{i-1} \\ x_{i-2} \end{pmatrix}$

(ii) Eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_1=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Basis of $V_{\lambda_1}$ is $B_{\lambda_1} =\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Basis of $V_{\lambda_2}$ is $B_{\lambda_2} =\begin {pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow D=\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}, S\begin {pmatrix} 1 & -1  \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, S^{-1}= \begin {pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}  \\ -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}$

(iii)
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S^{-1}A^nS = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S^{-1}(SDS^{-1})^nS=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S^{-1}(SD^nS^{-1})S=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}D^n= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & (-\frac{1}{2})^n \end{pmatrix}$

Is this correct so far? How to go on now?

Comment: No, because now you have $\begin{pmatrix}x_i\\x_{i-1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{ax_{i-1} + bx_{i-2}}{2}\\x_{i-1}\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $a$ and $b$ are only the initial values and are not part of the recurrence relation.

Comment: So it must be $\begin {pmatrix} x_i \\ x_{i-1} \end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}  \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin {pmatrix} x_{i-1} \\ x_{i-2} \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: It's easy to find the eigenvalues of eigenvectors (for diagonalizing $A$). First, observe that $[1\ 1]^T$ is an obvious eigenvector, with eigenvalue $1$. Then the other eigenvalue is $\text{trace}(A) - 1 = \frac{1}{2} - 1 = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading question (iii) correctly?  The usual approach is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (SDS^{-1})^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} SD^nS^{-1} = S\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} D^n\right)S^{-1}$

Comment: Also do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Comment: Yes, i mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, i've corrected it

Comment: @DanielV I think so, since he says in part four to deduce from part 3 $\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n$

Comment: @DanielV What do you mean? I'm unsure what you are you getting at

Comment: I think what you have is correct, apply the limit to the inside of the matrix and then use your recursive relation above to write $y_n = M \cdot y_1$ where $M$ is matrix depending on $A$ and you should be able to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(-\frac{1}{2})^n=0$, we have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}D^n= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & (-\frac{1}{2})^n \end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

To simplify the notation, we Define $X^\infty:=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X^n$ and $Y_\infty:=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}Y_n$

Then
$$A^\infty=SD^\infty S^{-1}=\begin {pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}  \\ \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore (with $x_1=\{a,b\}$)
$$y_\infty=A^\infty.x_1$$

From any component of vector $y_\infty$, we have
$$x_\infty=\frac{2}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}b$$

This is consistent because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{n-1}$.